# What's the difference between "Artist Name" and "Album Artist" in (foobar2000's) metadata fields in music digital file's metadata?

Tags: terminology

I think the answer is this: "Album Artist" is (are) main person(s) behind album creation, but if there's the particular track with the guest performer(s) named ***Album Artist feat. Jane The Vocalist - Acoustic Rock Song***, then in "Artist Name" field for that track goes ***Album Artist feat. Jane The Vocalist*** value while in "Album Artist" field goes ***Album Artist*** value.

Answer (score 1):

Album artist is for the overall album artist, and artist is for the actual artist of the song.  For example the first song on Sasha & Digweed's mix album Renaissance is Leftfield's "Song of Life" (I don't remember which mix).  Album artist would be Sasha & Digweed, artist would be Leftfield.